# Event Receiver not affecting until refesh the list

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a Sharepoint 2010 list. I have written event receiver code to update a field value in item added event. I am getting correct result, but it's not updating the field value until I refresh the list. Why?

Code:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)       
{
       base.ItemAdded(properties);

       SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb();
       SPList list = properties.List;
       int highestValue = 0;

       SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
       query.Query = @"<OrderBy>
                         <FieldRef Name='NextNo' Ascending='FALSE' />
                     </OrderBy><RowLimit>1</RowLimit>";

       SPListItemCollection itemcollection = list.GetItems(query);
       if (itemcollection.Count > 0)
       {
           SPListItem item = itemcollection[0];
           highestValue = Convert.ToInt32(item["NextNo"]);
       }

       SPListItem currItem = properties.ListItem;
       currItem["NextNo"] = highestValue + 1;
       currItem.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `ItemAdding` event receiver as this fires before the list is updated and will show your changes. The `ItemAdded` event fires after the list has been updated hence the need to refresh.